# Image uploader input goes out of the box

Tags: bug, status-declined

When trying to add an image while asking a question, I saw that the input goes out of the box as seen in the image below.

[image]

Browser: Firefox 18.0.2
Operating system: [Ubuntu 12.04.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) LTS (Precise Pangolin)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the non-standard way Firefox deals with the file input type size.

It also only manifests on Linux platforms - as such we feel our efforts are better directed elsewhere.